# Jersey Classpathscanning example jersey.config.server.provider.classpath

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

Can anyone give me example to use "jersey.config.server.provider.classpath". I want to try to lookuo my rest reources located in a java project. This project is added to [arent Dynamic web project in its class path. Follwoing it the web.xml where i have used this parameter for classpath scanning of rest resources:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>com.vogella.jersey.first</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>rest.resources</param-value>
    </init-param>
     <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classpath</param-name>
      <param-value>rpi.resources</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Is something wrong in this, as I am not able to point to my resource.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how do you are calling your web service ?

Comment: rpi.resources belongs to different project. rest.resources is in parent dynamic web project in which another java project has been added in its class path. This child project contains package rpi.resources. So I have to point to a resource which is in the child project added in the classpath. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Having only this in your `web.xml` is sufficient to locate ReST resources in your project.

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>rest.resources</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Just make sure `rest.resources` is a correct package where you are having all the resource files.

Comment: Thanks but rpi.resources belongs to different project.

rest.resources is in parent dynamic web project in which another java project has been added in its class path. This child project contains package rpi.resources.

So I have to point to a resource which is in the child project added in the classpath.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerProperties.PROVIDER_CLASSPATH documentation, this is the **web.xml** style configuration you will need:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>rest.resources;rpi.resources</param-value>
</init-param>
```

When you are in an IDE and your classloaders weaving your dynamic projects together, double check that the dynamic web project is referencing all your projects with your resources and providers.
See it here in working:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.scanClasses()
```